# How to replace text to a different format?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm using VB.net 2003 + Automation for Word 2007

```
Document.Content.Find.Execute("Subject/ Title:", , , , , , , , , "Subject/ Title: Insert Subject here")
```

I found the code above that is extremely useful for my project. It replaces the first string with the second. But now I need to bring my code one step further. I would like the text from after the colon to be underlined. I tried using a range but it didn't work. Appreciate any form of help!

Secondly, that only works if there's text to look for in the first place! I would like to put text in an empty cell. How do I locate the cell programmatically? It's the second table in the document's second row, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the text after colon in another string. and write something like this:

```
' Use a Red pen for the underline text decoration.
        Private Sub SetRedUnderline()
            ' Create an underline text decoration. Default is underline.
            Dim myUnderline As New TextDecoration()

            ' Create a solid color brush pen for the text decoration.
            myUnderline.Pen = New Pen(Brushes.Red, 1)
            myUnderline.PenThicknessUnit = TextDecorationUnit.FontRecommended

            ' Set the underline decoration to a TextDecorationCollection and add it to the text block.
            Dim myCollection As New TextDecorationCollection()
            myCollection.Add(myUnderline)
            TextBlock2.TextDecorations = myCollection
        End Sub
```

The above code I found uses the TextDecoration Class, you can see the further documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752372.aspx#Y1178

Comment: that's for .net framework 4. i'm still using 1.1. are there alternatives? i just need it to be underlined.

Comment: I think the TextDecoration class is available from .NET 3.0 framework.

Comment: i'm using 1.1. is it possible to set the text + font in an object and use the "replace" function? or is it better to "search" the document for the string and set it to underline?